# How to make Website stretch horizontally

Tags: stretch

I'm trying to make a horizontal menu bar stretch fully across the screen without any gaps. So far it's somewhat working but there is a small gap on the far left.

Below is my code.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>New Design</title>
<link href="CSS/page2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="main">
<div id="header">

<div id="menu">

<ul id="ulmenu">
<li>Home</li>
<li>Portfolio</li>
<li>About Me</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>

</div>

<br />

</div>


<div id="content">
<br />
<br />
<br />


</div>

<br />
<br />


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
#main {
position: fixed;
margin-top: -17px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
float: left;
padding-left: -15px;
}
#main #header {
font-family: "Arial Black", Impact, Arial, sans-serif;
width: 100%;
height: 59px;
z-index: 30;
position: fixed;
margin-top: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-color: #CCC;
margin-right: auto;
float: left;
}
#main #header #menu {
background-color: #960;
height: 50px;
position: relative;
width: 800px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: -7px;
}
#main #header #menu ulmenu {
color: #FFF;
list-style-type: none;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
}
#main #header #menu ul li {
    display: inline;
text-align: center;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-left: 30px;
font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
color: #FC0;
font-size: 24px;
}
#main #content {
width: 900px;
margin-top: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

From the code above, is this the best way of going about this?

Link to the page itself.

http://carerra.ulmb.com/page2.html

Edit: Thanks guys, got it working now.

Comment: The demo link is FULL of ads! and pop-ups.

Comment: I love Adblock, didnt see anything ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "margin:0px" to your body. Then there shouldnt be any space at the sides.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your stylesheet;

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```